# How Render one page to another page in ruby on rails in jquery(Not a Partial View)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, redirect

How to Redirect One Page to another in Ruby on Rails Using  Jquery Event, it is not a partial view it is Another controller view please help to solve my issue .....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From jQuery you can redirect to another page from the current page jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
    window.location.href = "/controller-name/action-name";
 });
```

If you are passing any params then you can use like this

```
window.location.href="/controller-name/action-name?params_name=<%= @obj.param %>"
```